# AIML <topic> no match

Tags: chatbot, aiml

```
<category>
   <pattern>Q3 income _</pattern>
       <template><delay>2</delay>
       <set name = "topic">Q4</set> I am from UK. May I know What your home town is. </template>

   </category>
   
   <topic name = "Q4">
   <category>
       <pattern>_</pattern>
       <that>_ MAY I KNOW WHAT YOUR HOME TOWN IS</that>
       <template><delay>1</delay><set name = "topic">Q5</set> Good to know.</template>
   </category>
   </topic>
```

The hometown question's answer can't be captured by topic Q4.

Answer (score 0):

The underscore wildcard indicates 1 or more words, but in the sentence you are checking, you have no more words before "May I know....". Miss out the underscore and it will work.

```
<topic name = "Q4">
   <category>
       <pattern>_</pattern>
       <that>MAY I KNOW WHAT YOUR HOME TOWN IS</that>
       <template>
           <delay>1</delay>
           <set name="topic">Q5</set> Good to know.
       </template>
   </category>
</topic>
```